# connection between the distribution of energy levels and spacings between prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, prime-numbers, quantum-mechanics

I'm a student in university, I'm new in this forum. My teacher told me to use it for my research. I came to ask for advice and help. The research is about the connection between prime numbers and energy levels in quantum physics. I don't have any idea and no knowledge how to start the subject. I hope to get help from you.

Comment: See Part 5 of this book: http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8220.html

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a charming story behind this: an exchange between Dyson and Montgomery. Here is a [nice and quick rendition](https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2013/primes-random-matrices) of the account, among many. You take it from there.

Answer (score -1):

One interesting reference is https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01230473 and http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/newmaterial.htm.

Comment: the first link isn't working for me sir , I can't get the article

Comment: @jhon96: On the contrary, both links are perfectly accessible.